# Machine learning with constraints on features

Tags: machine-learning, regression, optimization

I am working on a learning to rank problem. I have queries and documents related to every query which I have to rank. I used lightgbm ranker to fit the model. Some of features are very important and if they are changed the fitted model predicts a better score for that document and thus a better rank.

Lets say, for a single query id, I have a group of documents `d1....d5` each having features `f1...fn`.
I change the features `f1,f2,f3` for document `d4` and it pushes the rank of `d4` from 4 to 3.

1. What should be the values of these features `f1,f2,f3` that can push the rank for document `d4` from 4 to 1 subject to the condition that `f1+f2+f3=45` is always satisfied ? (i.e. the sum of new modifications for `f1,f2,f3` should be always equal to 45 )

As far as I understand this problem is simply a constrained optimization problem. In such a problem we have an `objective function` and `constraints`. In my case I do not have a mathematical equation that relates rank to my features `r=f(f1....fn)` but I do have a learned model which I can use as an objective function.

**Follow up question**

All this made me think of another question. In the case of `OLS`, which is a constrained optimization problem, the constraints present in this kind of optimization are always on the coefficients.

2. If I would like to have constraints on the `predictors` does it really make sense ? How does it relate to my problem ?

I think the objective function of a regression problem and the objective function of constrained optimization problem i mentioned above are different.
I would really appreciate some thoughts on this, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I didn't understand the problem very well, but it looks like [genetic learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) could be a good direction to study.

Essentially a genetic algorithm works by iteratively trying many combinations of values for some features, evaluating "something" based on the features, selecting the best combinations and starting again with a combination of the best features so far. The goal is to eventually converge to an optimal combination of values.

Comment: thanks for the reply ! I edited my question